# User name in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I want to get current user's name. As documentation describes, I should user User.name method. Tried to use it as in the example - didn't work.
Tried this:

```
val = User.current.name
```

And this:

```
user = User.find(User.current.id)
val = user.name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do something strange with your Redmine instance, you should always have a `User.current`. So you should also be able to use `User.current.name`.

As this did not work, as you said, could you please elaborate a bit on what *exactly* didn't work?

Comment: Even when not logged in, User.current is the anonymous user which returns "Anonymous" for User.current.name

Answer (score 0):

You need a session or a cookie with a current user assigned (see the application controller) so you cant just console in and ask for the current user.