# Username in "Welcome text"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

How can I use current username in welcome text field of Redmine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible put of the box, but you can write a *very* simple plugin which adds a wiki macro. Or you could just try the one below :)

Just create a new directory in your `vendor/plugins` directory called `redmine_username_macro`. Then put this code into `vendor/plugins/redmine_username_macro/index.rb`.

```
require 'redmine'
Redmine::Plugin.register :my_user_plugin do
  name 'User Macro plugin'
  url 'http://dev.holgerjust.de/projects/redmine-misc'
  author 'Holger Just'
  description 'Add macro for inserting the current user.'
  version '0.1'
end

Redmine::WikiFormatting::Macros.register do
  desc "Insert the name of the current user. Example: !{{username}}"
  macro :username do |obj, args|
    h(User.current.name)
  end
end
```

Comment: And how can I invoke this macro from "Welcome text" field?

Comment: Well, just write something like "Welcome {{username}}". See http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormatting#Macros for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just like i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653281/user-name-in-redmine), try `User.current.name`.